# Summary report contain misleaded statistics jmeter

Tags: jmeter

after running my performance script , the statistic report generated is quite confusing.

Response Time :6s minimum
90th pct:4.53s
95th pct:4.9s

How come minimum response time is greater then 90th and 95th percentile , am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not be the case, the relevant code lives under [StatCalculator.java class](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/e7ff6eddd361b18784a827fdacb41a012d20d1c5/src/jorphan/src/main/java/org/apache/jorphan/math/StatCalculator.java#L153)

If you do believe that this is a JMeter bug - you should [raise an issue in JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

The first thing they will ask you is your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) so if it doesn't contain top-secret information you can update your question with the .jtl file contents so we would be able to look into the issue as well.

P.S. Any chance you're using a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) with non-default [naming policy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#naming_policy)? If yes, it might have an impact on results
P.P.S. Any change you're using [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) or amending sample results on the fly via [Groovy scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)? If yes, it also may influence the test metrics